# How to append a comma to an array var within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Inside a foreach loop I am assigning an array to a variable.

Because this array is within a loop it will output more than once.

Because it will output more than once I need the end of the array to have a comma so it doesn't break the array for each time it returns and instance of the array.

Is there a way to do this? 
- I found ways online but they only showed how to do this with strings in foreach loops, to either add or remove the comma at the end of the last foreach loop.

My code is below to explain.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Start our framework config arrays
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$options = array();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// MENU - Layout Settings
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

$options[] = 
array(
    'title'  => 'Layout Settings',
    'name'   => 'layout-settings',
    'icon'   => 'fa fa-cog',
    'fields' => 
    array(

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TAB - Layout Settings
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        array('type' => 'tabbed', 'id' => 'layout_settings', 'tabs' => array(

            return_post_type_layout_settings()

        ))

    ),
);

// Our return array function

function return_post_type_layout_settings() {

    $public_post_type = get_post_types(
        array(
            '_builtin' => TRUE,
            'public'   => TRUE
        )
    );

    sort($public_post_type, SORT_NATURAL);

    foreach($public_post_type as $post_type) {

        $layout_options = 

            array('title' => ucwords($post_type) . ' Layout', 'fields' => array(

                array('id' => $post_type, 'type' => 'grid', 'span' => '6-12', 'fields' => array(

                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // FIELD - Header Settings Panel
                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

                    array('message' => 'Enable ' . ucwords($post_type). ' Header Settings?', 'video' => 'QAEjuDpIaE4', 'type' => 'title_with_help'),
                    array('id' => $post_type . '_enable_header', 'type' => 'switcher'),

                ))

            )) // << I need to comma to post at the end of this array
            // because in my array above this will output more than once

        ;

        return $layout_options;

    }

}
```

Comment: If there is a better way to do this I'm ears, but this is what I have so far in trying to achieve these options to load for each public post type returned. If I could just get the ending comma it should output fine, as I am testing it.

Comment: I think multiple `return` statement in foreach loop will not work the way you expected. You need to cascade your results to a single variable output within your foreach and return by the end. (or use [Generator Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php)).

Comment: I'd usually add all values to a single array, then use [implode](http://php.net/implode) to add commas in-between items.

Comment: Wait ... the code doesn't make sense. What value do you expected to have in your 'tabs' array? Can you provide an example value for it?

Comment: Hi. I think you may be right about the multiple return, but not entirely sure because I haven't been able to get pass the comma issue. The value within my tabs array is one instance of the foreach loop. Here is a screenshot of that within the array @ http://take.ms/Ov544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues with the code. And there is nothing to do with actual commas. But rather the data structure of function output.

### Code Receiving the Function output

In this piece of code:

```
<?php

$options[] = 
array(
    'title'  => 'Layout Settings',
    'name'   => 'layout-settings',
    'icon'   => 'fa fa-cog',
    'fields' => 
    array(

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TAB - Layout Settings
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        array('type' => 'tabbed', 'id' => 'layout_settings', 'tabs' => array(
            return_post_type_layout_settings()
        ))

    ),
);
```

The `tabs` is declared only as an array with 1 value. There is no way you can put multiple value into `tabs` like this. It should be modified like this:

```
<?php

$options[] = 
array(
    'title'  => 'Layout Settings',
    'name'   => 'layout-settings',
    'icon'   => 'fa fa-cog',
    'fields' => 
    array(

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // TAB - Layout Settings
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------------

        array('type' => 'tabbed', 'id' => 'layout_settings', 'tabs' => return_post_type_layout_settings())

    ),
);
```

### The Function

Then you need to modify your function to return the correct array format:

```
function return_post_type_layout_settings() {

    $public_post_type = get_post_types(
        array(
            '_builtin' => TRUE,
            'public'   => TRUE
        )
    );

    sort($public_post_type, SORT_NATURAL);
    $layout_options = array(); // initialize $layout_options as array

    foreach($public_post_type as $post_type) {
        // append each options into $layout_options
        $layout_options[] = 
            array('title' => ucwords($post_type) . ' Layout', 'fields' => array(
                array('id' => $post_type, 'type' => 'grid', 'span' => '6-12', 'fields' => array(

                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // FIELD - Header Settings Panel
                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    array('message' => 'Enable ' . ucwords($post_type). ' Header Settings?', 'video' => 'QAEjuDpIaE4', 'type' => 'title_with_help'),
                    array('id' => $post_type . '_enable_header', 'type' => 'switcher'),
                ))
            ));
    }

    // return after $layout_options is finished
    return $layout_options;

}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Small overlook led to another led to a great misuse of much time. Thank you! Life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to have `$layout_options` be an array of multiple `["title"=>"My Layout", "fields"=>[..]]` objects? If so, I'd do something like this:

```
function return_post_type_layout_settings() {
    $public_post_type = get_post_types(
        array(
            '_builtin' => TRUE,
            'public'   => TRUE
        )
    );
    sort($public_post_type, SORT_NATURAL);
    $layout_options = array();
    foreach($public_post_type as $post_type) {
        $layout_options[] = 
            array('title' => ucwords($post_type) . ' Layout', 'fields' => array(
                array('id' => $post_type, 'type' => 'grid', 'span' => '6-12', 'fields' => array(
                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    // FIELD - Header Settings Panel
                    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
                    array('message' => 'Enable ' . ucwords($post_type). ' Header Settings?', 'video' => 'QAEjuDpIaE4', 'type' => 'title_with_help'),
                    array('id' => $post_type . '_enable_header', 'type' => 'switcher'),
                ))
            ))
        ;
    }
    return $layout_options;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Yes I think we are saying the same thing. For each post type I want the array to output with my options array. Normally I would write out the array, but I can't determine how many post types are on a user's site. So I'm trying to make the array of options output based on the post types detected. I tried your method and played with some of the code too, but all attempts returned nothing. It just broke my array output so no options at all were returned. Here is a screenshot of my output. Highlighted in red is what I need to generate for each post type. Tab & Fields. @ http://take.ms/Jb7g3

Comment: @NoahjChampion Could you provide a code example of what `$public_post_type` might look like, and then what you would expect `$layout_options` to look like as output?

Comment: This questions is answered above but I'll answer for someone else who might need to differentiate for themselves. This was an easy thing, haha, I just was off as to where I was running my function. If I would have looked at older code I could have spotted that. So the answer above can show the array return I needed. $public_post_type is a Wordpress function and the doc of it can be found @ https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types#Output_a_list_of_all_public_custom_post_types - Thanks for helping! Appreciate it! #Salute